# Is $f(x)=\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}$ continuous at $x=1$?

Tags: functions, continuity

Given $f(x)=\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}$. The function is said to be discontinuous at $x=1$ but since we can simplify it and rewrite $f(x)=x+1$, this removes the discontinuity. So is the function continuous or discontinuous at $x=1$

How do the two forms of $f(x)$ differ as both expressions are equal to each other. What stops us from simplifying the earlier expression and saying the function is continuous ?There was a similar question here but it didn't address my latter point.

Comment: The two "forms" of $f(x)$ are not equal to each other as their domains are not equal. By manipulating the first form into the second, you have allowed $x=1$ to be defined on the function since there is no longer a denominator.

Comment: @Jc12 since we use the "=" sign  in relating both expressions, should both expression contain the same domain . Should x=1 not be defined for the simplified form as someone mentioned below that we assume it when simplifying.

Comment: I agree, though you can not equate to say the first form is therefore continuous since the second form is due to the domain difference.

Comment: $f(x) $ is not defined at $x=1$

Comment: The "=" sign equates only the mapping rules. Recall that a function is a triple $(D,R,x\mapsto y(x))$ of a domain, range and a mapping rule, hence in order for two functions to be equal, all three defining parts must be equal. If $g(x)=x+1$ then $g$ is the function $(\mathbb R,\mathbb R,x\mapsto x+1)$ but $f$ is the function $(\mathbb R\setminus\{1\},\mathbb R\setminus\{2\},x\mapsto (x^2-1)/(x-1))$.

Comment: @Randy Makes sense.

Comment: Food for thought.  Suppose $f(x) =x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2$ when $x\ne 3$ but $f(3)=0$.  Is $g(x)$ continuous at $x= 3$.  $f(x) =g(x)$ for all the points in $\mathbb R$ except that one point $x=3$ where $f(3)=9$ but $g(3) =0$. So can we just rewrite $g(3) =9$ and say its continuous as it's only one point and it's equal everywhere else?  Is that any more or less valid than rewriting $f(x)=\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ as $x+1$?  $f(1) =\frac {1^2 -1}{1-1}=\frac 00$ which is undefined.  We do *NOT* have $f(1) =1+1=2$.  We just DONT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x) = 2$, so the singularity is removable.

Let $$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}  f(x), & x \ne 1\\ 2, & x=1 \end{array}  \right.$$  The function $g(x)$ is continuous.

So, yes, $f(x)$ is discontinous but this discontinuity is easily repaired.  If you were to graph $y=f(x)$, it would be the straight line $y=x+1$ with the point $(1,2)$ removed.

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Comment: Sure, you are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

No.  No.  No.

$f$ is not merely discontinuous at $x=1$.  It is undefined and doesn't exist and $x=1$ is not in the domain.  $f(x)$ and $x=1$ *does not exist*.

"since we can simplify it and rewrite f(x)=x+1"

We can do no such thing at all.

$g(x) = x+1$ is an completely different thing than $f(x) = \frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$.  The difference is $x+1$ exists at $x=1$.  But $f(x)=\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ does *not* exist at $x=1$.  As they do *different* things at $x=1$ they are *not* the same thing at all.  That's all.  If two functions have different domains they are different things.  That they take the same values on the points of their domains in common is irrelevant.  They have different domains. End of story.

"How do the two forms of f(x) differ as both expressions are equal to each other."

$f(x)$ does not have two forms and the expressions $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ and $x+1$ are *not* equal to each other.  At $x=1$ we have $x+1=2$.  But at $x=1$ we have $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ is non-existent.  It DOES NOT EXIST!

"What stops us from simplifying the earlier expression and saying the function is continuous ?"

The same thing that stops us from switching bean sprouts with chocolate syrup and saying the snack is healthy.  Just because the snacks are exactly the same at $ingredient \ne bean\ sprouts$, the are different at $ingredient = bean\ sprout$ so the snacks are different things.

$x+1$ and $\frac {x^2-1}{x-1}$ are different things because one is defined at $x+1$ and the other isn't.  As they are different things they are .... different things.

If a guy says "I'm not a doctor but I play one on TV, now let's look at that appendix"... run...

Comment: I think l will never make this mistake again( in this life and the next.  : )

Answer (score 1):

You can only simplify the expression assuming that $x\neq 1$. Since on $x=1$, the function is undefined, therefore the function is discontinuous at $x=1$.